# Sub-defined error in the LARGE part of this formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a conditional formatting formula that I recorded, but I want to make it dynamic. I understand I need to add in `LastRow` and stuff like that, but I keep getting the quotations screwed up.

this is it recorded:

```
Formula1:"=CA$50452>=LARGE($CA$50452:$DO$50452,10)"
```

but I want to make it like this:

```
Formula1:"=CA2:CA" & LastRow >= "Large(CA2:CA" & LastRow & ")", 10)
```

but I keep getting a `Sub-defined` error on the `LARGE` part of the formula.

Any thoughts?

rest of script:

```
Sub Top10()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet111")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("CA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim LastCol As Long
LastCol = ws.Cells(LastRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Range(ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "CA"), ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol)).Formula = "=SUM(CA2:CA" & LastRow & ")"

Range("CA2").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=CA2:CA" & LastRow & ">=LARGE(CA2:CA" & LastRow & "), 10)"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Formula1:"=CA" & LastRow + 1 & " >= Large(" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "CA"), ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol)).Address(1,1) & ", 10)"
```

Also remove the line:

```
Range("CA2").Select
```

And replace all the `Selection`

With:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "CA"), ws.Cells(2, LastCol))
```

Comment: you're amazing, now I can start applying this to all other scenarios, thank you so so much!

Comment: something I noticed is that it's doing `1` less than the top 10, so it's just updating the `top 9` when I do this: `Formula1:"=CA" & LastRow + 1 & " >= Large(" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "CA"), ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol)).Address(1,1) & ", 10)"`

Comment: Without seeing the data I cannot speculate as to why.

Comment: no worries, I can see that it works if I just add +1 more number to it, so `11` shows the top 10. Close enough. Thanks again

Comment: Hey, I found out what was going on. You have the LastCol area to replace anything explicitly referenced in the header or subtotal range. How can I tell it not to reference the last column? adding a `- 1` to all of the `LastCol` areas?

Comment: @nicklanta that would refer to the column to the left of the last column.  If that is what you want then yes.